Manipulating a Excel Spreadsheet within a Word document using python
I use a word document with an embedded excel spreadsheet for invoicing.
The issue: Even so my current solution works:

Edit template word document via docx and save it as invoice_number.docx
Edit template excel spreadsheet via openpyxl and save it as temp_spread.xlsx
Insert temp_spread.xlsx as OLEObject in invoice_number.docx using win32com.client

Step 3. takes disproportionately longer than all other steps (database access, price calculation and file editing are completed in about 0.4 seconds), while insertion takes about 6.4 to 7 seconds.
I am currently looking for a faster solution. Normally I would provide Word and Excel files, however:
If you can make it work with some combination of Word documents and Excel spreadsheets, I can customize my templates to match. (Doesn't have to be newest file formats)

Don't do that to begin with. The customers need both Word and Excel installed just to display the invoice. Opening the document will open an Excel instance in the background to render the Excel document. That was in fashion in the late 1990s-very early 2000s but no longer. Ever since the XML-based formats were released in 2006, all application, no matter the language and OS, can generate Word or Excel files without embedding or using Word and Excel

Why not create a Word file with tables instead? Word always offered data-driven text generation in the form of mail merge, and there are Python libraries that perform mail merge without using Word itself. Since 2006 though programs can generate what they want directly

@PanagiotisKanavos the invoice files are not send to the customers. They are either printed or turned into pdf and send to the customers via email. We keep them for our accounting. The reasons it "has to be" excel spreadsheets: 1. You should be able to adjust the price calculation manually (might be needed (so far it wasn't), taxes are calculated inside the excel sheet). 2. The accounting is done by my father and well he can't change unless it is very, very, very similar to the current way (for example a "browser version" of the word/excel invoices).

In that case the process will remain slow, especially if the code is inefficient. When you use win32com.client you're actually using COM Automation to control the applications. Every call is a call to a remote application. You can't make this run faster than what you'd get from manually embedding Excel files in Word. You can make this slower though if the script tries to modify the properties of remote objects one by one, because each property operation is a remote call as well.

A faster way would be to use linking instead of embedding, either in the UI or through code. In this case you're only adding a link to the Excel file, not copying it into the Word document. When you open the Word document, Word asks Excel to open the Excel file and render it inside Word. You can't delete or move the Excel file, otherwise Word won't be able to locate it

@PanagiotisKanavos Sadly docx doesn't find any OLEObject. win32com.client does find an OBJECT, however it doesn't recognize it as excel spreadsheet even if the OLEObject/Excel spreadsheet was embedded by win32com itself.Just embedding the link would work, but would be undesirable (basically 2 files for each invoice). I am not fixated on Python for this. If there was a workaround (e.g. via c++) that would also be an option for me.
